# Find this integral $I=\int\frac{1}{\sin^5{x}+\cos^6{x}}dx$

Tags: integration

> How find this 
>   $$I=\int\dfrac{1}{\sin^5{x}+\cos^6{x}}dx$$

this problem is from  china exam.so I think have closed form

I find this 
[wolf]

[wolf]:http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F%28%28sinx%29%5E5%2B%28cosx%29%5E6%29dx[image]

such this example: use wolf give us too hard form,But I can use hand to solve it:

[How find this integral $I=\int\frac{1}{\sin^5{x}+\cos^5{x}}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/600885/how-find-this-integral-i-int-frac1-sin5x-cos5xdx?rq=1)

see this wolf

[image]

Comment: Do you know what does [**wolf**](http://images2.fanpop.com/images/photos/8200000/Taylor-Jacob-jacob-black-8293644-1280-853.jpg) mean?

Comment: can you send us a link from this exam?

Comment: Wolfram's solution is telling you that the solution is in terms of a root of a polynomial which is not solvable by radicals.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner,sorry,I can't find link,because china most exam problem don't like post intenet

Comment: I'd start by changing $\cos^6x=(1-\sin^2x)^3$ and then do the change of variable $u=\sin x$. I'm not sure this works, but it's a start.

Comment: Use the [Weierstrass substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution).

Comment: @hjhjhj57 that doesn't work because there is no $\cos x$ in the numerator

Answer (score 1):

The best i can do:

By substituting
\begin{align*}
t&=\tan\frac x2\\
\sin x&=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\\
\cos x&=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}
\end{align*}
the integral can be written as
$$2\int\frac{\left(1+t^2\right)^5}{t^{12}-6t^{10}+32t^7-20t^6+32t^5+15t^4-6t^2+1}\,dt$$
This integral is solvable by partial fractions if we know the roots of the denominator, but the roots can probably not be expressed in any nice way. Wolfram Alpha is just calling the roots $\omega$ I believe.